# “cycle was detected in the build path” when there is no cycle, how to resolve?

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex

While looking for an answer to this question I found this question [Eclipse is telling me a cycle was detected in the building path, but that's not true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3446314/2773169). In my case I have tried removing the project and refreshing it from source control with no improvement. I have tried changing the value of Java->Compiler->Building Circular dependencies. With it set to Error I get two errors one with type “Java Problem” and one with type “Flex Problem”. When I set it to Warning I get only the Flex Problem error. I do not believe there is a cycle in the build path because:

1. I have looked at the dependencies and their dependencies and so on.
2. There is only one project in the workspace with this error. AFAIK you need at least two projects to have a build cycle.
3. Others who have gotten this same set of code from source control do not get this error.

So assuming there is no actual cycle, and given that I have deleted the project folder and refreshed from source control, where are the files or cached folders in Eclipse or Flex that may be causing this false report?

Comment: Did you use the _Plug-ins Dependencies_ view and the _Compute Dependency Extend_ feature to find the cycle?

Comment: You haven't shown us why the message is wrong, or what the "Flex Problem" message is.

Comment: @nitind the message is “cycle was detected in the build path of project123”.  The message is wrong because there is no cycle in the build path. In fact there cannot be because a single project cannot have a cycle. There has to be 2 or more.

Comment: I was not aware of the Plug-ins Dependencies view, but I am not working on a plug-in.  I was not able to find Compute Dependency Extend, but found my solution in the mean time.

Comment: In the Plug-in/Manifest editor right-click a dependency and select _Compute Dependency Extend_ to search where this dependency is used in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was incorrect, there was a cycle, just not on the project in question.  The project that reported the cycle was the only Flex project in the workspace, hence the only one that was ignoring the setting in Eclipse to list a build cycle as a Warning.  This is a good example of why using that setting is a bad idea, and actually fixing the cycle is the right way to go.  Unfortunately this is a "legacy" application and I am not being given the time to fix it.  The issue was that one of the projects had a Maven profile set that included the project it was referenced from, hence the cycle.  So for myself a reminder to check all the ways that projects define dependencies.  Also to not assume that the issue is with the thing generating the error.  Sorry for the distraction.